# How to make gradle output display test results

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I recently updated intellj and now my gradle output window looks different. Previously it would display which tests had passed or failed under a dropdown arrow, now all I can see are the gradle tasks themselves.

How can I revert back to how it used to look? Going back an intellj version didn't help as the output still looked the same.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Here's my run configuration:
[image]

Comment: Your code is not compiling, so you also can't run any tests until this is sorted out.

Comment: I cancelled it manually, it looks similar even if it passes

Comment: I've uploaded a better before picture that shows what it looks like after the test is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Enable **Show Passed** option for tests in Run/Debug tool window:

[image]

Comment: I don't have those options anymore, I can get them to appear if I run the feature file by clicking the green arrow on the line numbers, but not when I use my gradle run configuration

Comment: I've uploaded what my run configuration looks like